# php script to convert signature to image and upload to Server

Tags: android, jquery, codeigniter, mobile, signature

Explanation of the issue: I have form with a signature pad on a mobile app, the user signs on it and submits the form. Then the sign should convert in to image and then upload in to folder server location.

I have used the following code to do that.

**PHP Script**

```
$img = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $this->input->post('imgsource',TRUE));
    $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
    $data = base64_decode($img);        
    file_put_contents($this->input->post('file_name',TRUE), $data);
```

**JS Script**

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
    // added `width` , `height` properties to `img` attributes
    img.width = "250px";
    img.height = "250px";
    img.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64_string;
    var dt = new Date();
    var timeupload = dt.getDate() + "" + (dt.getMonth()+1) + "" + dt.getFullYear() + "" + dt.getHours() + "" + dt.getMinutes() + "" + dt.getSeconds();
    img.name = $("input[name='uid']").val()+"_"+currentTaskId+"_"+timeupload+'.jpeg';
```

AjaX Call to Service(written in Codeginter)

```
data: queryString+"&username="+localStorage.getItem('user')+"&password="+localStorage.getItem('password')+"&imgsource="+base64_string+"&file_name="+img.name+"&user_id="+$("input[name='uid']").val()+"&task_id="+currentTaskId,
```

here imgsource is the signature that I get from mobile app, decoding in to base64 to create an image and then pushing in to Server location.

the actual problem is the image get uploaded in to Server, when i try to download the image and see the image, its not readable/visible (ie, signature is not seen as an image)

Can anyone please suggest me in doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You should url encode your base64 string before sending it to the server. Use
         `encodeURIComponent(base64_string)`          in your AJAX call.